# Access Apple's APFS volumes from Windows

Tags: windows-10, macos, ssd, recovery, photorec

I have a SSD drive which is removed from my Macbook. I need to recover my files from this drive. Because of not having enough space on another Macbook drive, I must to use Windows computer but the computer doesn't recognise the drive which has apfs volumes.

How can I represent apfs drive on windows? I'm using PhotoRec recovery application. I should show up my drive like others to use recovery application.

Comment: Ah, PhotoRec doesn't work with APFS. I did a quick search for a free utility to recover from APFS on Windows but didn't find anything. You could try [R_Studio](https://www.r-studio.com/data-recovery-after-erase-APFS.html) which will *show* you recoverable files but it won't let you save them without paying.

Answer (score 0):

There are usually a number of ways to access Mac formatted volumes from non-Mac computers. As APFS is still pretty new your choices are a little more limited and/or less mature than utilities that read HFS+.

There is a company that specializes in cross platform file system access. They offer NTFS access on the Mac and HFS+ access on Windows and it seems also [APFS.](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/apfs-windows/)

I have no specific experience with this or other (open source) tools nor any interest in the company but judging from their success with other FS access I would tend to trust them.

A little searching for *APFS for Windows* might come up with alternatives, free and otherwise.

Comment: If the file recovery program needs direct access to the disk, will that be of any use?

Comment: It may, best to ask the folks that make that software to be sure it does *exactly* what you need.